# "Namespace Prefix Inkscape" error in an SVG file

Tags: svg, adobe-illustrator

I recently created a vector image on Adobe Illustrator and now the SVG file is only creating the initial stages of the design before coming up with an error:

> *"error on line 353 at column 77: Namespace prefix inkscape for original on path is not defined"*

My aim is to recover the file, or at least most of it, so I don't have to recreate it all from scratch again

I have already search Stackoverflow and found a number of pages with similar issues, but none of them seem to have worked (Though this may be due to my inexperience). I have tried to delete the section of code, but that just bugs out the next line.

```
<g id="g15008_6_" transform="matrix(0.08741528,-0.2790867,-0.2187316,-0.04878567,559.67434,1071.9284)">

<path id="path15012_6_" inkscape:original="M 777.03125 425.3125 C 768.33974 425.44114 761.38075 427.77622 758.21875 432 C 754.17515 429.77494 753.40566 434.1846 753.8125 433.78125 C 762.55281 449.54413 772.13283 446.95767 782.90625 443.96875 C 787.01791 442.78165 791.56668 441.35498 795.46875 439.375 C 803.5544 437.78559 801.04722 435.98205 801.96875 433.65625 C 803.43347 428.93203 792.51988 426.16857 786.21875 425.9375 C 783.0142 425.48504 779.92842 425.26962 777.03125 425.3125 z " inkscape:radius="-2.8900177" sodipodi:type="inkscape:offset" class="st18" d="
    M416.7,1473c-16.9-41.3-23.3-76.9-20-94.6c0.9-4.7,0-10.6-2.4-15.4c21.7,6,34.5,17.8,43.5,33.5c10.4,18,17,43.8,24.4,73.9
    c5.4,22.8,10.9,47.8,13.6,69.6c0.2,1.4,0.5,2.9,0.9,4.3c3,10.3,4.4,16.9,4.9,20.3c0.5,3.4,0.1,2.7,0.4,1.7
    c0.3-0.9,0.6-0.8-0.7,0.3c-1.3,1.2-3.9,3.3-6,7.9l0.4-0.8c-0.3,0.5,0.9,0.6-1.3-0.7s-6.4-5.3-10.9-11.3c-9.1-12-19.9-31.2-26-45
    c-0.2-0.5-0.5-1-0.7-1.4C429.1,1501,422.3,1486.8,416.7,1473L416.7,1473z"/>
```

Comment: Please try changing `inkscape:original="M 777.......` with `d="M 777.......` in a text editor

Comment: @enxaneta not a good idea as there _is_ a `d` attribute, and it's different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to open the file with [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org). Choose *Save as...Plain SVG*. The saved file will be rid of all `inkscape:` and `sodipodi:` namespace prefixes that only Inkscape understands.

Comment: this doesn't fix in my case. Why would Inkscape insert them at the beginning?

Comment: how would one do exactly that programmatically? Say I have 200 svgs that I want to remove the prefixes from